# Token based Authentication using django + mongoengine

Tags: django, authentication, mongoengine

I'm using **mongoengine + django**. I need to use **Token-based Authentication**. I googled a lot but found with **django.contrib.auth**. Somewhere I found **mongoengine.django.auth** but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861077/django-auth-with-mongoengine-db) where I found.

May be, I get downvote for this question but my question is simple.

`Token-based Authentication using django+mongoengine. Most of them are using mysql but I have mongoengine.`

If it is not possible to implement this scenario. Please suggest me something else where I can achieve my goal.

Comment: you need this in django rest framework or simple django?

Comment: Using simple django.

Answer (score 0):

### Token Authentication

** Create a Token Collection

```
class MongoToken(Document):
    key = StringField(max_length=44)
    user = ReferenceField('**USERMODEL NAME**', required=True)
    created = DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **values):
        super(MongoToken, self).__init__(*args, **values)
        # super().__init__(*args, **values)
        if not self.key:
            self.key = self.generate_key()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created =  datetime.now()

        return super(MongoToken, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_key(self):
        return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(22)).decode()

    @staticmethod
    def token_validator(token=None):
        token_user = MongoToken.objects.get(key=token)
        if token_user:
            user = get_document_or_404( **USERMODEL NAME**,id=str(token_user.user.id))
            return user
        else:
            return False    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.key
```

Create Token :

```
[1]: token,created = MongoToken.objects.get_or_create(user=**user_object**)
[2]: user_token = token.key ### a12222dsdasdasd45787784546

Token Validation [ views.py ] [CBV]
[3]:

def post(self, request):
        user_token=request.QUERY_PARAMS['token']
        user_token = str(user_token)
        return_data = {}
        try:
            ### This query will return while it got success
            user = MongoToken.token_validator(token=user_token)

            return_data['status'] = 200
            return_data['message'] = 'success'
        except:
            return_data['status'] = 404
            return_data['message'] = "User Details not found"
```

Comment: Can i use this generated token in "Authentication Header" for API ?

Comment: I'm getting this error - `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_or_create'`